# I have problems with python2.7-minimal when intalling anything (sudo apt install)

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, python-2.7

I think I have a serious dependency error with python2.7-minimal as every time i want to install anything, this appear. Does someone knows how to correct this or uninstall python2 (if possible) ?

```
(base) user@username:~/programs/nodejs$ sudo apt install pypy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpython2-stdlib linux-image-5.19.0-43-generic
  linux-modules-5.19.0-43-generic linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-43-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  pypy-lib
Suggested packages:
  pypy-doc pypy-tk
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  pypy pypy-lib
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 16.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 88.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 pypy-lib amd64 7.3.9+dfsg-1 [2 484 kB]
Get:2 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 pypy amd64 7.3.9+dfsg-1 [13.7 MB]
Fetched 16.2 MB in 4s (4 191 kB/s) 
Selecting previously unselected package pypy-lib:amd64.
(Reading database ... 231562 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../pypy-lib_7.3.9+dfsg-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pypy-lib:amd64 (7.3.9+dfsg-1) ...
Setting up pypy-lib:amd64 (7.3.9+dfsg-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pypy.
(Reading database ... 232846 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../pypy_7.3.9+dfsg-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pypy (7.3.9+dfsg-1) ...
Setting up pypy (7.3.9+dfsg-1) ...
running pypy rtupdate hooks for 7.3
running pypy post-rtupdate hooks for 7.3
Setting up python2.7-minimal (2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1) ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
/usr/bin/python2.7: can't open file '/usr/lib/python2.7/py_compile.py': [Errno 2
] No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package python2.7-minimal (--configure):
 installed python2.7-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returne
d error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python2-minimal:
 python2-minimal depends on python2.7-minimal (>= 2.7.18~); however:
  Package python2.7-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python2-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python2.7:
 python2.7 depends on python2.7-minimal (= 2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1); however:
  Package python2.7-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python2.7 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro
r from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message ind
icates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    Processing triggers for man-
db (2.10.2-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python2.7-minimal
 python2-minimal
 python2.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Do you actually need python2.7 for anything? If you are running Ubuntu 20.04 and above, it may be a good idea to remove python2.7 altogether

Comment: Yes, I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, so I guess it's a good option. So then is it safe to remove python2.7 completely?

Comment: Yes, it is safe to remove python2 completely. `sudo apt remove  python2.7-minimal python2-minimal python2.7` and `sudo apt autoremove`